# How Extract value from Response using Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter-plugins

In Jmeter how to extract File_Name & ReqId value  from below response using Regular Expression Extractor

{"FileCode":["Aadhar"],"File_Name":"271954143_1_1.jpg","Aadhar_Features":[{"Confidence":"79.46","File_Code":"UIA","Count":1},{"Confidence":"87.87","File_Code":"GOI","Count":1},{"Confidence":"88.25","File_Code":"Aadhar_Slogan","Count":1},{"Confidence":"92.36","File_Code":"SatyamevaJayateLogo","Count":1},{"Confidence":"92.99","File_Code":"AadharLogo","Count":1},{"Confidence":"97.01","File_Code":"Aadhar","Count":2}],"ReqId":"REQ_1639032634869","Classes":[{"Confidence":[96.21741771697998,98.64940047264099],"Coordinates":["383,269,110.0,27","375,882,105.33333333333333,28"],"Count":2,"Name":"AadharNo"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be Regular Expression Extractor? [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence it makes sense to consider using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) instead, it allows executing arbitrary [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) queries and store the results into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

In your case the JMESPath expressions would be just `File_Name` and `ReqId`, example configuration:

[image]

Refer the extracted value as `${File_Name}` where required, the same setup could be used for `ReqId`

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: I want to use a regular expression extractor to extract values from this response & then those values will be input for another API , so how to do that