# I Want extract value from json response using Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, run one API and get the below response.  I want to extract File_Name & ReqId value from the below response using Regular Expression Extractor **using only one "Regular Expression Extractor"** . and pass these two values to another API, so how do that?

{"FileCode":["Aadhar"],"File_Name":"271954143_1_1.jpg","Aadhar_Features":[{"Confidence":"79.46","File_Code":"UIA","Count":1},{"Confidence":"87.87","File_Code":"GOI","Count":1},{"Confidence":"88.25","File_Code":"Aadhar_Slogan","Count":1},{"Confidence":"92.36","File_Code":"SatyamevaJayateLogo","Count":1},{"Confidence":"92.99","File_Code":"AadharLogo","Count":1},{"Confidence":"97.01","File_Code":"Aadhar","Count":2}],"ReqId":"REQ_1639032634869","Classes":[{"Confidence":[96.21741771697998,98.64940047264099],"Coordinates":["383,269,110.0,27","375,882,105.33333333333333,28"],"Count":2,"Name":"AadharNo"}]}

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286077/how-extract-value-from-response-using-regular-expression-extractor/70286264#70286264) some wise man suggested using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) as it's faster, easier and more reliable.

If despite this you prefer using Regular Expression Extractor - here is the regular expression for the `File_Name`:

```
"File_Name"\s*:\s*"(.+?)"
```

[image]

and here is the one for the `ReqId`

[image]

Example Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

[image]

Example JMeter Variable usage:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)